# perceptions of machine learning techniques from different careers?

Tags: machine-learning

I have followed some basic courses in Machine Learning at Computer Science Faculties, but I have found, and correct me if I am wrong, different perspectives or ways to tackle things down depending on the background of a lecturer. For example:

- A statistician would use inferential statistics to tackle some subjects, such as neural networks or the Vapnik theory for the part of SVM.
- A computer scientist would be more oriented to the algorithmic part, leaving some mathematical details out of a lecture.
- A mathematician will look some techniques more oriented to Calculus instead of statistics or algorithms.

The question is if there are different perspectives in which one student could learn about ML techniques?

Comment: The question sounds very broad, and it sounds like you've already provided at least one reasonable answer to the question by giving some examples of different perspectives where a student can learn ML techniques.  Can you edit the question to focus it on something more specific, where it is clearer how you plan to evaluate candidate answers?